# Liquid. Looping through an array with an if condition then want to store the output of that in another array

Tags: shopify, liquid

```
{% assign leg = {{Predept.legs}} %}
{% for legs in {{leg}} %}
  {% if {{leg[forloop.index0].direction}} == 'R' %}
            {{leg[forloop.index0].arr_station_name}} 
  {%endif %}
{%endfor %}
```

I want to put the output of this for loop into another array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Jeet!

First, you don't ever nest the Liquid tags.  Your basic loop should look something like this:

```
{% assign legs = Predept.legs %}
{% for leg in legs %}
  <!-- Cool code & stuff here! -->
{% endfor %}
```

Now, in Liquid you can only create a new array by using the `split` filter on a string.  We can also create a string by wrapping other commands with the `capture` tag. Putting that together, we get something like:

```
{% capture leg_data %}
  {% assign legs = Predept.legs %}
  {% for leg in legs %}
    {% if leg.direction == 'R' %}
      {% comment %}Output delimiter if needed {% endcomment %}
      {% unless found_one %},{% endunless %}
      {% assign found_one = true %}
      {{ leg.arr_station_name }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign leg_data = leg_data | split: ',' %}
```

That will give us an array of all of our `arr_station_name` for the desired legs, but you may note that `capture` is also capturing all of the whitespace in there as well.  If we need to prevent that from getting into our nice little array, we can use the whitespace-stripping `-` character on our tags to control that, giving:

```
{%- capture leg_data -%}
  {%- assign legs = Predept.legs -%}
  {%- for leg in legs -%}
    {%- if leg.direction == 'R' -%}
      {%- comment -%}Output delimiter if needed {%- endcomment -%}
      {%- unless found_one -%},{%- endunless -%}
      {%- assign found_one = true -%}
      {{- leg.arr_station_name -}}
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}

{%- assign leg_data = leg_data | split: ',' -%}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wish that it were otherwise!  The limitations of Shopify's implementation of Liquid leave a lot to be desired (and a lot of kludgy, hacky workarounds like the above in its wake)